# How much faster is NCHW compared to NHWC in TensorFlow/cuDNN?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

[The official TensorFlow performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models) states:

> Most TensorFlow operations used by a CNN support both NHWC and NCHW data format. On GPU, NCHW is faster. But on CPU, NHWC is sometimes faster.

How much faster is NCHW compared to NHWC in TensorFlow/cuDNN, for convolution? Are there any references or benchmarks for this?

Also, why is it faster? As I understand (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8286)), TensorFlow for NHWC on GPU will internally always transpose to NCHW, then calls the cuDNN conv kernel for NCHW, then transpose it back. But why does it do that? The cuDNN conv kernel also works for NHWC. Maybe at some point they did the comparison and the cuDNN conv kernel for NHWC was very slow. But is that up-to-date? And how big was the difference? What are the technical reasons that NHWC is so much slower? Or is the cuDNN kernel for this case just not well optimized?

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: @MaxB: Well, not fully. I extended my question a bit to make more clear what I want to know.

Comment: "A bit"?! You added half a dozen new Qs, using the link I provided too ...

Comment: I'm not downvoting you -- just withdrawing my earlier +1.

Comment: @MaxB: In what way did I make my question worse by adding more details? Your answer doesn't fully answer my original question, so I added some details about what should be added to really get an understanding of why NCHW is faster than NHWC. Your answer basically just says "because they do it that way". Why? They could have done differently.

Comment: You didn't even ask "why" in the first revision. You also made no mention of cuDNN. You changed the question after getting the correct answer. Anyhow, this is pointless...

Comment: @MaxB Any answer to how much faster it is will obviously also implicitly explain why that is. Also already in the very beginning I mentioned CUDA. The only reason I mentioned TensorFlow was because I read that in their docu, but of course, if you really want to understand why things are the way they are, you need the full picture, i.e. what are the underlying reasons. Look at other StackOverflow answers. If something can't be done, it explains why it is that way. And of course you can always just write your own wrapper which calls NHWC directly, so you are technically wrong with your answer.

Comment: **"Any answer to how much faster it is will obviously also implicitly explain why that is."** --  saying **"Bill is 2x faster than John"** doesn't implicitly explain why that's true. A 5-year-old would know that.  I say that without exaggeration. I've never met a 5-year-old that would make the logical mistake that you've made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that most implementations of simple convolutions (not talking winograd or fft here), end up doing some kind of simple matrix multiplication, which means that in their inner loop they multiply some values from both tensors and sum the results.

On a CPU implementation, using SSE or AVX optimization, it's faster to do this along the C dimension, because you just multiply-add the values 4 by 4 or 8 by 8, and then do the reduction (sum your 4 or 8 accumulations) at the end once you added all the C dimension.

On a GPU however, doing a reduction across threads is a more costly operation (at least it was until Kepler introduced wrap-level atomic operations), so historically it has been optimized so that each thread in a wrap reads consecutive (in memory) HW values, and do the accumulation over parts of C with a loop.

Note though that the latest nvidia cards (RTX), now have tensor multiplication cores, that can process small blocks in one operation, including the reduction over a small portion of C, so on these cards it's actually faster to use NHWC (or hybrid NCHWC formats).

Answer (score 4):

As of TF1.1, you can't even call NHWC directly. TF does the conversion to and from NCHW. So, regardless of the efficiency of the implementation of NHWC in cuDNN, from the TF users' perspective, NCHW is faster:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8286

The performance ratio will of course depend on the problem, but my sense of it is that it's big, and you don't want to use NHWC (on GPU), if you can avoid it (It seems likely that you'd be wasting memory too)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much of a point in manually optimising the layout, especially because `data_format="channels_first"` looks a lot more verbose than sticking with the default throughout TensorFlow, and because the internals should take care of it.

I'd expect at most a couple of percents faster training times with NCHW, and over time I'd expect this performance difference to go away as XLA JIT compilation matures.

With Keras you can try both pretty easily with `K.set_image_data_format` so try both and see what difference it makes for your particular model.

Here is a small benchmark with a VGG model https://gist.github.com/carlthome/51d62cbf5fc23098418eef93b11a5d78

Comment: We have a publication on this now, [here](https://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/publications/download/1134/Bozheniuk-ICASSP-2020.pdf), where we compare NHWC vs NCHW, and **NCHW is almost 2.5 times faster**. So this is definitely not just a couple of percents.

Answer (score 0):

CPU side:

Let's assume their inputs and filters are all transposed to do GEMM: for NCHW the inputs shapes after im2col are `W[out_channels, in_channels * filter_height * filter_width]` and `X[in_channels * filter_height * filter_width, out_height * out_width]`, for NHWC the inputs shapes after im2col are `X[out_height * out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]` and `W[filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, out_channels]`, the former one will do `W*X` well the later one will do `X*W` , as you can see the difference only comes at `out_channels` comes first or `out_height * out_width` comes first, you can nearly tell any performance difference because GEMM are highly optimazed which will use some pack and tiling techquene to do small patch matrix multiplication.

The biggest palnety for NCHW is from im2col, because for NHWC you can memcpy the inner moset in_channels data while NCHW need to jump from row to row, channel to channel to get a complete patch of data(And this's also what XNNPACK do for performance improvements).

GPU side:

Don't know much about it yet.